# Transition between rooms for floating engineered wood flooring

Tags: transition, engineered-flooring

I am currently looking to install 20mm thick oak lacquered engineered wood flooring using "floating method". The flooring has tongue and grove so I will use glue into the grove.

I will put the same flooring into all rooms as well as landing (corridor).
The floor would have around  7.5m length and 5m width.

Different guides/videos/people say different things about transitions. I.e. floating floor should have transition every 10 meters.

Do you think I should put transition strips on doorways so that each room has it's own "floor"? Ideally I would like to avoid that as these strips don't look super nice.

Edit: Added floorplan

[image: Floorplan]

Comment: Can probably be done as one complete floor, landing and rooms, if you want everything the same.  Transitions allow more decorating choices for each room or landing concerning walls and floor.  Measurements and planning more of a pain if done as one complete section.

Comment: Your question, as it stands, is asking for _opinion_. That's off topic here. Please see [ask]. Now, if you had given us a rough layout diagram we could hedge toward objective answers. You haven't even said if you'll exceed 10m.

Comment: Hello,
I am actually looking for advice on whether this is a good idea or not. I have mentioned size of the floor, but you are right - floor plan was attached.

Thank you

Comment: If you could define what a "good idea" is in your head, that would give us an opportunity to give you a more objective answer. Bear in mind, some people think that jumping out of a perfectly good airplane is a "good idea" while other people think that getting into an airplane in the first place is a "horribly bad idea". "Good idea" is purely subjective, and we do not answer those types of questions here.

Comment: That said, running the flooring in the same direction throughout the whole house, with no breaks at any doorways gives a sense of continuity through the house. On the other hand, being willing to break it up room-by-room with a transition at each doorway, allows you to lay the flooring in the direction that makes the most sense for _that_ room. It also minimizes the error should a corner not be 90° somewhere (that _never_ happens! ;). If you run along a wall that's not 90° as your starting point, you'll be farther and farther out with one continuous run of flooring...

Comment: I am mostly worried about integrity of the floor. Many people don't even recommend to float an tongue and grove engineered wood floor. 

I understand the concerns around angles and direction.

Answer (score 1):

The best advice should come from the flooring manufacture. They know best how the product will react. Consult them.